# How to make localhost as first match host name for shared ip(127.0.0.1)?

Tags: 14.04, localhost

To install Cloud Manager successfully in my system *(14.04/64b)*, I shared my localhost ip `127.0.0.1` to my system account.

I edit my **host(arul-pc)** ip in `/etc/hosts/` from `127.0.1.1` to `127.0.0.1` as shown below,

```
arul@arul-pc:~$ sudo nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       arul-pc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now when I get host name for `127.0.0.1`, it returns `arul-pc`. I want to make `localhost` as first match for mentioned ip(`127.0.0.1`).

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
127.0.0.1       arul-pc
```

And add this line:

```
localhost       arul-pc
```